# Inserting dynamic variable into a long multiline string (C#)

Tags: c#, string, insert

I'm trying to dynamically insert a string as a portion of a query into a larger string that holds the entire query. The problem is, when I close the double quote, add the string variable, then open another double quote for the remainder of the query, everything after the inserted string variable doesn't seem to understand that it is inside double quotes. I can't really share my code, the query is far too long. But attached is the exact layout of how I have it:
[Layout of string insertion code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY3cK.png)

Everything below DynamicVariable seems to think it is not enclosed in double quotes when I know it is. I also forgot to add the @ symbol to the attached layout. The CreateQuery string is a verbatim string literal. Not sure if that might be part of the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You might be prone to sql-injection if you build your query parameters dynamically. Use parameterized queries. Apart from that you have to show the code causing the issue. Note that there might be a missing space before the 1st `AND` and `Condition3` + `Condition3` are in quotes.

Comment: 1) Look up "SQL Injection" (https://bobby-tables.com/). 2) look up _Verbatim Strings_ (with `@`) and 3) _Interpolated Strings_ (`$`).  The latter two address your question.  The first one addresses an important security issue

Comment: If it's a verbatim string, why not just embed the newlines and make it more readable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure code and your computer don't think so what does "seems to think it is not enclosed in double quotes" mean exactly?